# Can I communicate with my server in a way that can't be figured out and spoofed by a third party?

Tags: ios, sockets, http, nsurlsession, tcp

It seems there are a couple choices within Xcode/iOS to communicate with my server, using simple HTTP requests or creating a full blown socket system. What vulnerabilities does each have? My main concern is that I can't allow someone to replicate a call that's not from my app, like you could spoof an AJAX call by examining a webpage's Javascript and getting the address for the call. Obv it wouldn't be so simple with a phone app, but I don't know what's possible for hackers.

Comment: encryption + ssl pinning should keep you covered

Comment: @Fonix Ok, I'll look that up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use HTTPS.
2. [Override the TLS chain validation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/OverridingSSLChainValidationCorrectly.html) to fail if the public key doesn't match the one stored in your app.

In Apple's [TLS validation doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/OverridingSSLChainValidationCorrectly.html) below, start with "Listing 3  Overriding the trust object used by an NSURLConnection object", then add code so that if certificate evaluation succeeds, you check the key inside the challenge's protection space against a known-valid key (or keys) before allowing the connection to proceed.

Comment: Ok, thanks brotha. I'll look into it when I have time. I've already set something up using NSURLSession. I'm sure what you're referring to works with that also.